# Ist der Satz "Uns ist der Film interessant " richtig?

Tags: grammatical-case

Ich möchte gern wissen, warum der Satz

> Uns ist der Film *interessant.*

falsch ist, während z.B.

> Uns ist der Film *wichtig.*

offensichtlich richtig ist.
Haben wir konkrete Grammatik für manche Adjektive in dieser Kombination ?

Comment: Nein, ist er nicht.

Comment: Gibt es einen Grund, anzunehmen, daß er richtig wäre?

Comment: @infinitezero Richtig ist er nicht, aber es gibt ähnliche Redewendungen wie "Uns ist der Film wichtig".

Comment: @Paul Frost ich verstehe nicht , warum "Der Film ist uns wichtig " richtig ist , aber "Der Film ist uns interessant " ist falsch . Hat das einen konkreten Grund?

Comment: @Simafo Ja, er ist falsch. "Uns/mir ist etwas wichtig" bzw. "Das ist uns/mir wichtig"  ist Gegensatz dazu korrekt.

Comment: @Paul Frost zum Beispiel : Haben wir "Es ist mir interessant " oder? Warum haben wir mit diese Kombination mit "uns " nicht?

Comment: @Simafo Manche Adjektive passen in das Schema "Das ist jemandem ... ", andere nicht. Den Grund kann ich nicht benennen, ich bin aber sicher, dass jemand diese Lücke füllen wird.

Comment: @Paul Frost Ach so !! Vielen Dank

Comment: @David Vogt Weil ich diese Kombination für andere Adjektive früher gesehen habe , glaube ich , dass das möglich richtig wäre.

Comment: @infinitezero könnten Sie sagen , warum es so ist? Warum ist "Uns ist sicher " richtig , aber " uns ist der Film interessant " ist falsch

Comment: Bitte editiere deine Frage doch dahingehend, Simafo :)

Comment: Er ist allemal ungebräuchlich, aber nicht falsch.

Comment: Ich finde, wir informieren den Fragesteller falsch, wenn wir sagen, der Satz "uns ist der Film interessant" sei "nicht falsch". Kein Muttersprachler würde das im Hochdeutschen so sagen, sondern immer "für" benutzen, also kann man m.E. auch nicht sagen, dass das richtiges Deutsch ist.

Comment: Warum soll die Frage geschlossen werden? Sie ist interessanter als viele andere ohne Close-Votes.

Comment: @HalvarF: Ich finde, wir informieren den Fragesteller **richtig**, wenn wir sagen, der Satz "uns ist der Film interessant" sei "nicht falsch". Einige Muttersprachler sagen das genau so im Hochdeutschen. Entsprechende Belege habe ich soeben ans Ende [meiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/60649/1487) angefügt. Also kann man m.E. **sehr wohl** sagen, dass das richtiges Deutsch ist.

Comment: Seht Euch mal die spannende Diskussion an, die die Frage ausgelöst hat und erklärt mir dann die Close-Votes.

Answer (score 3):

In dem Satz “Uns ist der Film interessant” wird das Adjektiv "interessant" mit dem Dativ erweitert. Das ist im Hochdeutschen zumindest sehr unüblich, wenn auch die Belege von Hubert Schölnast zeigen, dass es vorkommt. Die normale Verwendung in gegenwärtigem Deutsch wäre: "Für uns ist der Film interessant".

Es gibt Adjektive, die man direkt mit dem Dativ (oder anderen Fällen) erweitern kann, und andere, bei denen das nicht geht. Eine (unvollständige) Liste von Adjektiven, die man direkt erweitern kann, gibt es hier:

https://deutschegrammatik20.de/adjektiv/adjektiv-adverb-rektion/adjektive-die-kasus-direkt-regieren/liste-adjektive-mit-dativ/

Bei Adjektiven, die nicht direkt mit einem Kasus erweiterbar sind, muss man eine Präposition einsetzen, zum Beispiel "für".

> Der Preis ist **dem Kunden** egal. ("für den Kunden" würde auch gehen)

> Der Preis ist **für den Kunden** unbezahlbar. ("dem Kunden" wäre hier falsch)

> Diese Information ist **mir** neu. Der Bericht enthielt keine **mir** neuen Informationen. ("für mich" würde auch gehen)

> Diese Information ist **für mich** hilfreich. Der Bericht enthielt keine **für mich** hilfreichen Informationen. ("mir" wäre falsch)

> Deine Ausrede ist **mir** unverständlich. Schon wieder kommst du mit einer **mir** unverständlichen Ausrede zu mir.

> Deine Ausrede ist **für mich** nicht nachvollziehbar. Warum du immer wieder **für mich** nicht nachvollziehbare Ausreden anführst, ist für mich nicht nachvollziehbar.

> Du bist **mir** lieb und teuer.

> Du bist **für mich** einzigartig.

> Der Film ist **den Betroffenen** wichtig.

> Der Film ist **für die Betroffenen** interessant.

Es gibt auch Adjektive, die direkt mit anderen Fällen erweiterbar sind:

> Der Festgenommene ist **des Einbruchs** verdächtig. ("verdächtig" mit Genitiv)

> Der Film war **den Eintrittspreis** wert. ("wert" mit Akkusativ)

Comment: -1 für die nachweislich falsche Behauptung, der Satz “Uns ist der Film interessant” sei nicht richtig. Beispiele, die das Vorkommen ähnlicher Wendungen belegen, habe ich [meiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/60649/1487) hinzugefügt.

Comment: Mich überzeugen Ihre verlinkten Beispiele ehrlich gesagt nicht davon, dass das Standardsprache (und nicht künstlerische Freiheit oder veralteter Sprachgebrauch) ist, aber ich finde in den üblichen Wörterbüchern nichts dazu und habe die Aussage etwas abgeschwächt.

Comment: Auch "Standardsprache" ist ein Kontinuum, in gewisser Weise. Ich stimme dir völlig zu, das die Konstruktion kollokational (aus mir unerfindlichen Gründen) so beschränkt ist, dass man sie beinahe nur sprachspielerisch einsetzen würde, und somit borderline inakzeptabel. Gleichzeitig ist sie aber, wie Hubert betont, in syntaktischer und semantischer Hinsicht komplett grammatisch, transparent, und verständlich; als L1-Sprecher habe ich überhaupt kein Problem damit, außer dass man "das halt so nicht sagen würde".

Answer (score 1):

Der erste Satz ist gar nicht falsch. Er ist nur ungebräuchlich. Ich ändere nur mal die Reihenfolge der Satzglieder, so dass das Subjekt an erster Stelle steht und lasse das Wort *uns* vorerst mal weg:

> Der Preis ist egal.
> Diese Information ist neu.
> Deine Ausrede ist zu billig.
> Der Film ist wichtig.
> Der Film ist interessant.

Das sind alles einfache Sätze mit einem Subjekt und einem Prädikat. Das Prädikat besteht aus einem Verb, nämlich einer Form von *sein* und einem [Prädikativum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4dikativum) (das in einem Fall mit der Gradpartikel "zu" ergänzt wurde). Das Verb *sein* gehört zu den [Kopulae](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kopula_(Grammatik)), und ein Kopula und ein Prädikativum ordnen gemeinsam dem Subjekt eine Eigenschaft zu. Sie funktionieren gemeinsam also so ähnlich wie Attribute innerhalb von Nominalgruppen, mit dem Unterschied, das eine Nominalgruppen (*»der wichtige Film«*) noch kein ganzer Satz ist, die Konstruktion mit Kopula und Prädikativum hingegen schon.

So weit, so langweilig.

Nun gibt es im Deutschen aber noch den *[Dativus commodi](https://www.mediensprache.net/de/basix/lexikon/?qu=Dativus%20commodi)*, auf Deutsch: **Dativ des Nutzens** bzw. **Dativ des Nutznießers.** Das ist jene Anwendung des Dativ, bei der der Nutznießer einer Handlung im Dativ genannt wird:

> Eugen hat **mir** den Laptop repariert.

Damit sehr eng verwandt: der *[Dativus imcommodi](https://www.mediensprache.net/de/basix/lexikon/?qu=Dativus%20incommodi)* (**Dativ der Benachteiligung** bzw. **Dativ des Benachteiligten**):

> Jürgen hat **mir** mein Hemd zerrissen.

In vielen Grammatikbüchern werden diese beide Formen gemeinsam unter dem Begriff *Dativus commodi* behandelt, weil grammatisch kein Unterschied besteht, und der einzige Unterschied darin besteht, ob die Auswirkung erfreulich oder unerfreulich ist, was aber eher eine semantische Kategorie ist.

Das Wichtige dabei: Das ist ein [freier Dativ](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/2028), also ein Dativ, der **nicht** vom Verb regiert wird. Mit anderen Worten: Es gibt kein Verb, dass den Einsatz dieser Form des Dativ verlangt. Es gibt aber auch kein Verb, dass den Einsatz des *Dativus commodi* (bzw. auch des *Dativus incommodi*) verbieten würde. Daher kann man dieses Satzglied immer hinzufügen, um auszudrücken, dass die beschriebene Handlung jemanden beeinflusst:

> Der Preis ist **dem Kunden** egal.
> Diese Information ist **mir** neu.
> Deine Ausrede ist **mir** zu billig.
> Du bist **mir** lieb und teuer.
> Der Film ist **den Betroffenen** wichtig.

Also auch:

> Der Film ist **uns** interessant.

Grammatisch gibt es daran nichts auszusetzen, klar verständlich ist der Satz auch, also spricht eigentlich nichts gegen seine Verwendung. Lediglich der Umstand, dass diese Konstruktion bei bestimmten Adjektiven üblicher ist als bei anderen, macht die Verwendung zusammen mit einigen Adjektiven zu einer ungewohnten Erfahrung.

---

### Beispiele

Weil mehrere Teilnehmer an dieser Diskussion die Korrektheit der Formulierung "das ist mir interessant" in Abrede stellen, möchte ich hier ein paar Beispiele aus Kunst, Literatur und Wissenschaft nennen, in denen genau diese Formulierung vorkommt, und zwar aus der Feder bzw. dem Mund von Hochdeutsch sprechenden Muttersprachlern. (Auf jeder verlinkten Seite kommt *»ist mir interessant«* vor.)

- in Projekt Guttenberg: [Karl May: Deutsche Herzen – Deutsche Helden](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/may/deuther6/chap022.html)
- in Wikisource: [Friedrich Schiller (Herausgeber): Neue Thalia, vierter Band](https://de.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Seite:De_Neue_Thalia_Band4_270.jpg)
- in Zobodat: [Dr. A. H. Krausse: Zur Insektenfaune Sardiniens (Entomologische-Rundschau)](https://www.zobodat.at/pdf/Entomologische-Rundschau_27_0171.pdf)
- im Hugo Schuchardt Archiv: [Brief von Hugo Schuchardt](http://schuchardt.uni-graz.at/id/letter/6670)

Die oben genannten Fundstellen sind alle schon etwas älter, es gibt aber auch welche aus dem 21. Jahrhundert:

- Artikel über steirischen Herbst 2005: [Jour Fixe mit Veronica Kaup-Hasler](https://igkultur.at/artikel/jour-fixe-mit-veronica-kaup-hasler)
- Kulturspitzen 2014: [Künstlerportrait Traude Feldschuh](http://www.kulturspitzen.com/php/index.php?nav=K%C3%BCnstler%202014&sub=Traude%20Feldschuh)
- Monopol-Magazin 8. Juni 2020 [Interview mit Daniel Richter](https://www.monopol-magazin.de/interview-daniel-richter)

Comment: Vieeelen Dank für Ihre vollständige Antwort

Comment: Der Satz ist sicher grammatisch korrekt und sogar verständlich, aber niemand würde das so ausdrücken. Oder vorsichtiger: Ich habe das noch nie in dieser Form gehört, was natürlich nicht gegen den Satz spricht. Auch der Satz "Der Film ist uns schwarz" ist grammatisch korrekt, hat aber keinen Sinn. Ich würde daher die Frage umformulieren: Warum ist der Satz ungebräuchlich und hört sich merkwürdig an? Das muss an der Kombination von "ist uns" und "interessant" liegen. Interessant ist mir, dass die Version "Der Film scheint uns interessant zu sein" gut klingt, obwohl er die gleiche Struktur hat.

Comment: Die Beispiele (Adjektive) in dieser Antwort sind aber alle so ausgesucht, dass sie mit dem Dativ funktionieren. Das ist aber nicht für alle Adjektive der Fall. Hir sind entsprechende Gegenbeispiele:

Der Preis ist unbezahlbar.
Die Information ist alt.
Deine Ausrede ist mangelhaft.
Du bist groß und stark.
Der Film ist interessant.

Das kann man nach alles entweder gar nicht oder nur mit "für jemanden" erweitern, nicht mit einem einfachen Dativ. Ich denke, es gibt einfach Adjektive, bei denen der Dativ funktioniert und andere wie "interessant", bei denen er nicht funktioniert.

Comment: @Paul Frost: "Der Film scheint uns interessant zu sein" hat eine andere Struktur: Das "Uns" gehört darin nicht zu "interessant" oder "sein", sondern zu "scheint".  Deshalb funktioniert es da.

Comment: @HalvarF " Ich denke, es gibt einfach Adjektive, bei denen der Dativ funktioniert und andere wie "interessant", bei denen er nicht funktioniert." Sehe ich auch so, muss wohl als Faktum akzeptiert werden.

Comment: Wenn der Dativ wirklich frei wäre, hätte man keine Erklärung dafür, dass *X ist mir interessant* so selten ist oder *X ist mir uninteressant* gar nicht (?) auftritt. Die Beobachtung, dass es Zeiten und Sprecher gibt, die immerhin *interessant* mit einem Dativ verbinden, spricht dafür, dass die Erklärung von @HalvarF richtig ist.

Comment: Der 1. und 3. Beleg aus dem 21. Jh. enthalten eine andere syntaktische Struktur und belegen somit nicht das Geforderte. Ein aktueller Beleg allein ist sehr dünn und könnte aus einem Fehler oder dem Idiolekt der Autorin resultieren. Dass die anderen Belege alle weit von der Gegenwart entfernt sind, deutet darauf hin, dass die Formulierung im gegenwärtig verwendeten Deutsch nicht mehr verbreitet ist. Anscheinend hat sich 'interessant' zu einem Adjektiv gewandelt, das den Gebrauch des freien Dativs blockiert.

Comment: In einer mittlerweile gelöschten Antwort wurde die These vertreten, dass die Existenz eines verwandten  Verbs den Gebrauch des freien Dativs unüblich macht. Z.B. wäre "Der Film interessiert uns" die primäre Form und "Der Film ist uns interessant" die verworfene Form. Das schien mir anfangs nicht unplausibel, aber es gibt auch dazu Gegenbeispiele: "Der Film langweilt uns" und "Der Film ist uns langweilig".

Comment: Interessant ist mir, dass die drei modernen Fundstücke aus dem österreichischen Sprachraum stammen. Ein Zeichen einer gewissen Divergenz? Das dritte Beispiel enthält den Satz "Diese Art der Malerei ist mir interessant geblieben". Interessanterweise klingt das für mich besser als die Präsenzform des Satzes, auch dieses Phänomen bedürfte einer Erklärung.